# Google Maps API: How to get street addresses only as results of Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Given the bounds of a specific city in the form of a `google.maps.LatLngBounds` type variable, I want to get street addresses from that specific area as results of the autocomplete feature.

I read that using bounds in Google Maps API gives only approximate results and that would work for me. Problem is: at the moment results are not even close to the specified area.

```
<input type="text" class="event_form_input" id="event_address" name="event_address" placeholder="Address" value="">
```

```js
var address_input = document.getElementById('event_address');
var address_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address_input,{bounds: event_city_bounds, types: ['geocode']});

address_autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(){               
                var event_address=address_autocomplete.getPlace();
})
```

What I am getting are both city names and addresses with no restrictions at all. I already checked the variable `event_city_bounds` and it always contains the correct bounds of any city I previously select (from another input menu).
Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Types supported in place autocomplete requests](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3):

> **address** instructs the Place Autocomplete service to return only geocoding results with a precise address. Generally, you use this
>   request when you know the user will be looking for a fully specified
>   address.

So you can try something like this

```
var address_autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address_input,{bounds: event_city_bounds, types: ['address']});
```

Comment: Just tried it and it does remove all city names from the suggestions, but I still don't get results biased towards the specific area. However, this is a start. Thanks!

Comment: "The results are biased towards, but not restricted to, places contained within these bounds". I think the key words here are "not restricted".

Comment: I read that, but the results I get are totally random, not "biased towards". Thanks anyways, I accepted your answer.

Comment: Maybe it means that there is nothing found within the bounds? For instance, when I set it to my current location (plus 500m in all directions), I get this https://i.imgsafe.org/8324f1c227.png. And when I search for addresses which don't exist in my town (Tomsk), I get this https://i.imgsafe.org/832d7d1d3d.png